# Como abrir sub menu de site no TwebBrowser pela aplicação delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10

Sou iniciando na programação, e tenho conhecimento bem básico sobre o assunto,
Atualmente eu carrego um site no TWebBrowser dessa forma:

`twSite.Navigate('https://farmaciapopular-portal.saude.gov.br/farmaciapopular-portal/login.jsf');`

`twSite.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('formLogin:j_idt20').Click;`
`twSite.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('formLogin:no_login').Value := USUARIO;`
`twSite.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('formLogin:senha').Value := SENHA;`

`while ( twSite.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE ) do`
`begin`
`Application.ProcessMessages;`
`Sleep(0);`
`end;`

`twSite.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('formLogin:j_idt29').Click;`

Primeiro eu:

- carrego o site no TwebBrowser
- Clico no botão 'Ciente' que aparece no popup ao acessar o site
- Insiro o Login e Senha nas tags html do site.
- Clico pra logar. Logado com Sucesso.

Após isso, existe um Menu no site: **Cadastro de Vendedor** e 2 Sub Menus dentro, que são: **Cadastro em Massa** e **Cadastro Manual**.

O problema é que preciso acessar o menu **Cadastro Manual**, porém, a TAG HTML dele não tem nome como usei no inicio do meu código com *GetElementById*

quando eu inspeciono elemento do submenu, eu tenho isso:

`<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt26'),{'j_idt26:j_idt38':'j_idt26:j_idt38'},'');return false" class="sf-with-ul" style="float: none; width: auto;">Cadastro Manual</a>`

Como eu posso acessar este sub menu, sem ter um nome para pegar com o GetElementById ?